# How to provide iot service to our devices during aws code update roll out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, esp8266, nodemcu, aws-iot

We are using AWS IOT for our home automation product.

Recently we started to face a new issue with AWS IOT services.

The problem is when AWS IOT team release new code updates, they disconnect certain devices from mqtt.

Our devices connect to mqtt , aws disconnects them immediately , ultimately leading to connect -> disconnect cycle.Our devices make shadow update/get request whenever they connect to mqtt.

As a result this causes high iot message usage. The worst thing is mqtt service remains unavailable during this time so users can't use our product and they start calling our customer support and we have no valid reason to satisfy them, leading to very bad user experience.

This issue has been occurred three times in last couple of months.

We tried to get some solution from AWS developer support but no benefit.

Could anyone please suggest a way that we can use to provide service to our customers when this issue occurs?

We are using nodemcu esp8266 and mongoose os on hardware side.